# Efficient way to determine if a pixel is in safe bounds

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
int isSafe(int pixelNumber, int safeStart, int safeWidth, int height, int width)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        if (safeStart + width * i <= pixelNumber && pixelNumber < safeStart + width * i + safeWidth)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This tells if a pixel is safe or not. So I will be calling this function several times 
for several pixel values from 0 to some number. Is there some way to code it more efficiently
 so as to avoid running the forloop every time

Comment: What is `pixelnumber`? An index into a one dimensional array of `width * height`? Can you give a more concrete example? Like if width and height are both 400 would safeStart be something like 10 and safewidth 380? I assume you're just constraining on the left and right edges.

Comment: Yes, correct it's an index into a one-dimensional array width * height. But you can arrange it in the form of width x height matrix and then the safe ones are those that start with column number safe start till column with number safeWidth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original function can be simplified to this:

```
int isSafe(int pixelNumber, int safeStart, int safeWidth, int height, int width)
{
    return pixelNumber >= safeStart &&
           (pixelNumber - safeStart) / width < height &&
           (pixelNumber - safeStart) % width < safeWidth;
}
```

However, if `height` is the overall image height and `safeStart` can be greater than or equal to `width`, the function ought to be changed as follows to check that `pixelNumber` is not on a row above the image height:

```
int isSafe(int pixelNumber, int safeStart, int safeWidth, int height, int width)
{
    height -= safeStart / width;
    return pixelNumber >= safeStart &&
           (pixelNumber - safeStart) / width < height &&
           (pixelNumber - safeStart) % width < safeWidth;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is there some way to code it more efficiently
> so as to avoid running the forloop every time

Yes.

You have three straigth lines. Like;

```
Y1(i) = width * i + safeStart
Y2(i) = width * i + (safeStart + safeWidth)
Y3(i) = pixelNumber
```

And your check is

```
 Y1(i) <= Y3(i) && Y3(i) < Y2(i)
```

So you are really checking that the line `Y3` is always between the lines `Y1` and `Y2`.

To do that, all you need is to check the endpoints, i.e `i = 0` and `i = height - 1`

Picture:

[image]